# How to give money to player which username is stored in a string value - Roblox lua

Tags: lua, concatenation, roblox

So I'm making a game on Roblox where you can pick up objects and sell them. however, the selling script is a normal Script (ran on the server), and I can't use

```
Game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
```

to find who to give the money to. the object that the user picks up has an

```
Owner
```

value, and when they touch it, it changes it to their username. so when the object touches the selling part, it looks at the owner, and gives the money to them (which is stored in a number value called Owner).

Here is my current code:

```
local part = script.Parent

local function onPartTouched(otherPart)--otherPart is the part that touched it
    if otherPart:FindFirstChild("Owner") == nil then
    else
        local owner = game.Players..otherPart.Owner.Value
        getowner.leaderstats.Bucks.Value = getprice.leaderstats.Bucks.Value + otherPart.Price.Value
        otherPart.Parent = game.ServerStorage
    end
end

part.Touched:Connect(onPartTouched)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just do game.Players[value.Value]

Comment: You wouldnt need to concat. Here is the code if you need it. 

local part = script.Parent

local function onPartTouched(otherPart)--otherPart is the part that touched it
    if otherPart:FindFirstChild("Owner") == nil then
    else
        local owner = game.Players[otherPart.Owner.Value]
        getowner.leaderstats.Bucks.Value = getprice.leaderstats.Bucks.Value + otherPart.Price.Value
        otherPart.Parent = game.ServerStorage
    end
end

part.Touched:Connect(onPartTouched)

Comment: You should use the `edit` feature just below your anser to edit your answer instead of writing the code as a comment. Much easier to read! :)

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
Game.Players.LocalPlayer
```

also just writing @agents answer too in proper format.

```
local part = script.Parent 
local function onPartTouched(otherPart)
    if otherPart:FindFirstChild("Owner") == nil then 
    else 
        local owner = game.Players[otherPart.Owner.Value] 
        getowner.leaderstats.Bucks.Value = getprice.leaderstats.Bucks.Value +otherPart.Price.Value 
        otherPart.Parent = game.ServerStorage 
    end 
end 
part.Touched:Connect(onPartTouched)
```

Comment: I said use localscript

Comment: Also my answer seems to be efficient and lagless to me atleast.